# Calculated Column as Title on SharePoint Calenar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am working in SharePoint to create a calendar that will pull the information from the  "Content Category" column and the "Title" column into the title field.

To do this, I am trying to create a calculated column that will pull from the two other columns. However, I am getting an error each time I try to create the calculated column. The formula I am trying to use is below. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

=Content Category&" : "&Title

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below formula:

```
=[Content Category]&" : "&Title
```

If you have a space in the display name of your column then you need to write it inside `[]`.

**Note**: To achieve this you can also use `CONCATENATE` function.

[CONCATENATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-5b0392b2-94ef-49ea-8532-4fdd3a69d362)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ganesh Sanap, do as Ganesh Sanap suggested.

You can use below formula:

=[Content Category]&" : "&[Title]

Or

=CONCATENATE([Content Category], " : ", [Title])

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#combine-first-and-last-names